# coding4fun toolkit error only in xaml page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to use TimeSPanPicker of coding4fun because I need to set seconds. So I installed the package from nuGet.
The TimeSpanPicker work if I declare it in the C# code, but in xaml I had this error:

[image]

i used this namespace with no error:

```
xmlns:c4fToolkit="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls"
```

And the classic silverlight toolkit is work properly.

THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace you are using is wrong (it changed from `Coding4Fun.Phone` to `Coding4Fun.Toolkit` since V2 for supporting Windows Store apps).

Here is the one to use:

```
xmlns:c4fToolkit="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls"
```